# Generalized Travelling salesman problem in Julia

Tags: julia, julia-jump, glpk

I'm working on a project, where I have to solve a GTSP.
THe project is about a primeminister that has to visit one city in every electorate (cluster) and has to start and end at city 1.

I have 17 different cities and 5 clusters (without city 1).
As of now I have written the following in Julia, but it doesnt seem to give me a corract answer, as I start by going from edge 1 to 1.. (see the output at the bottom)

I know I'm missing some constraints, but as of now I feel like I have tried everything, at it doesn't seem to work. Do you have any tips on constraints missing?

```
using JuMP
using GLPK

m = Model(GLPK.Optimizer)
n=17
cost = [0   506 635 91  385 155 110 130 490 368 154 68  610 641 471 265 255;
    506 0   355 415 585 475 480 500 605 320 380 440 360 235 81  480 440;
    635 355 0   602 390 495 560 531 295 675 640 575 705 585 435 420 755;
    91  415 602 0   347 118 75  94  457 280 63  27  520 550 380 232 235;
    385 585 390 347 0   240 305 276 120 590 410 320 835 745 575 125 582;
    155 475 495 118 240 0   65  36  350 365 181 91  605 610 440 125 353;
    110 480 560 75  305 65  0   29  415 348 138 48  590 625 455 190 310;
    130 500 531 94  276 36  29  0   386 367 157 67  610 635 465 161 329;
    490 605 295 457 120 350 415 386 0   625 520 430 865 770 600 230 680;
    368 320 675 280 590 365 348 367 625 0   240 300 250 285 245 475 150;
    154 380 640 63  410 181 138 157 520 240 0   90  480 515 345 295 175;
    68  440 575 27  320 91  48  67  430 300 90  0   545 577 407 205 262;
    610 360 705 520 835 605 590 610 865 250 480 545 0   190 295 715 400;
    641 235 585 550 745 610 625 635 770 285 515 577 190 0   170 645 435;
    471 81  435 380 575 440 455 465 600 245 345 407 295 170 0   475 385;
    265 480 420 232 125 125 190 161 230 475 295 205 715 645 475 0   467;
    255 440 755 235 582 353 310 329 680 150 175 262 400 435 385 467 0]

c1 = [13,14]
c2 = [5,9,16]
c3 = [4,6,7,8,11,12,17]
c4 = [3]
c5 = [2, 10, 15]

c = [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5]

#variable definition
@variable(m, x[1:n,1:n], Bin)
@variable(m, u[1:n])
@variable(m, z[1:n], Bin)

#objective function
@objective(m, Min, sum(cost[i, j] * x[i,j] for i = 1:n for j = 1:n))

# constraints - flow out of node
@constraint(m, sum(x[i,j] for j =1:n for i=1) == 1 )
@constraint(m, sum(x[i,j] for j in c5 for i =1:n) == 1)
@constraint(m, sum(x[i,j] for j in c1 for i =1:n) == 1)
@constraint(m, sum(x[i,j] for j in c2 for i =1:n) == 1)
@constraint(m, sum(x[i,j] for j in c3 for i =1:n) == 1)
@constraint(m, sum(x[i,j] for j in c4 for i =1:n) == 1)

#float into cluster
@constraint(m, sum(x[i,j] for j =1 for i = 1:n) == 1)
@constraint(m, sum(x[i,j] for j=1:n for i =c1) == 1)
@constraint(m, sum(x[i,j] for j=1:n for i =c2) == 1)
@constraint(m, sum(x[i,j] for j=1:n for i =c3) == 1)
@constraint(m, sum(x[i,j] for j=1:n for i =c4) == 1)
@constraint(m, sum(x[i,j] for j=1:n for i =c5) == 1)


# constraints - node order
for i=1:n, j=1:n
    if i != 1 && j!=1
        @constraint(m, u[i]-u[j]+(n-1)*x[i,j] <= (n-2))
    end 
end

# constraints - bounds on u
@constraint(m, u[1]==1)
@constraint(m, oneposl[i=2:n], u[i]>=2)
@constraint(m, oneposu[i=2:n], u[i]<=n)
optimize!(m)

println("Objective Value: ", JuMP.objective_value(m))
for i=1:n, j=1:n
   if JuMP.value(x[i,j]) > 1-1e-6
      println("Edge ", i, "-", j, " ", JuMP.value(x[i,j]))
      #println("x:", )
   end
end
```

I tried some different constraints, but I can see I need some constraints on the order going into and out of each cluster.

Comment: Have you considered marking an answer as accepted?

Comment: @trincot ofc. completely fogot to do it, but have done it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
for i=1:n
    @constraint(m, sum(x[i,j]-x[j,i] for j=1:n) == 0)
end
```

These constraints ensure the number of in-edges and out-edges of each node (not cluster) is the same.
Without this constraint, the cycle could enter a cluster at one node and exit from a different node.

Also, this constraint:

```
@constraint(m, oneposu[i=2:n], u[i]<=n)
```

might need to be:

```
@constraint(m, oneposu[i=2:n], u[i]<=length(c)+1)
```

to make sure the timing for each node in the cycle is limited to the length of the cycle. The length of the cycle is the number of clusters.

Comment: Thank you, the constraints helped, and solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

The JuMP documentation has a tutorial on TSP that might be helpful if you don't want to use MTZ: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/tutorials/algorithms/tsp_lazy_constraints

Here's how I would write your model (didn't check throughly, assuming I didn't make a mistake):

```
using JuMP
import HiGHS
cost = [
    0   506 635 91  385 155 110 130 490 368 154 68  610 641 471 265 255
    506 0   355 415 585 475 480 500 605 320 380 440 360 235 81  480 440
    635 355 0   602 390 495 560 531 295 675 640 575 705 585 435 420 755
    91  415 602 0   347 118 75  94  457 280 63  27  520 550 380 232 235
    385 585 390 347 0   240 305 276 120 590 410 320 835 745 575 125 582
    155 475 495 118 240 0   65  36  350 365 181 91  605 610 440 125 353
    110 480 560 75  305 65  0   29  415 348 138 48  590 625 455 190 310
    130 500 531 94  276 36  29  0   386 367 157 67  610 635 465 161 329
    490 605 295 457 120 350 415 386 0   625 520 430 865 770 600 230 680
    368 320 675 280 590 365 348 367 625 0   240 300 250 285 245 475 150
    154 380 640 63  410 181 138 157 520 240 0   90  480 515 345 295 175
    68  440 575 27  320 91  48  67  430 300 90  0   545 577 407 205 262
    610 360 705 520 835 605 590 610 865 250 480 545 0   190 295 715 400
    641 235 585 550 745 610 625 635 770 285 515 577 190 0   170 645 435
    471 81  435 380 575 440 455 465 600 245 345 407 295 170 0   475 385
    265 480 420 232 125 125 190 161 230 475 295 205 715 645 475 0   467
    255 440 755 235 582 353 310 329 680 150 175 262 400 435 385 467 0
]
n = size(cost, 1)
clusters = [
    [1],
    [13, 14],
    [5, 9, 16],
    [4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 17],
    [3],
    [2, 10, 15]
]
model = Model(HiGHS.Optimizer)
@variable(model, x[1:n, 1:n], Bin)
@variable(model, 2 <= u[1:n] <= n)
fix(u[1], 1; force = true)
@objective(model, Min, sum(cost[i, j] * x[i, j] for i in 1:n for j in 1:n))
@constraints(model, begin
    # Flow in and out of each node is the same
    [i in 1:n], sum(x[i, :]) == sum(x[:, i])
    # Flow into cluster is 1
    [c in clusters], sum(x[:, c]) == 1
    # Flow out of cluster is 1
    [c in clusters], sum(x[c, :]) == 1
    # MTZ subtour elimination
    [i in 2:n, j in 2:n], u[i] - u[j] + 1 <= (n - 1) * (1 - x[i, j])
end)
optimize!(model)
println("Objective Value: ", objective_value(model))
for i in 1:n, j in 1:n
    if round(Bool, value(x[i, j]))
        println("Edge ", i, "-", j, " ", value(x[i, j]))
    end
end
```

p.s., our discourse forum is also a good place to post if you need more help: https://discourse.julialang.org/c/domain/opt/13

Comment: Thank you! And thanks for the link to the discussion-group. Will defeinetly be looking into the forums there